# Declare Function Outside of a Functional Component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-functional-component

Take a look at the following functionaly component:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  function addPropData() {
   return prop.data.name
  }

  return (
  <div>{addPropData()}</div>
 )
}
```

I am wondering if it is possible to declare the `addPropData` function **outside** of `MyComponent`.  For example, something like this:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  return (
  <div>{addPropData()}</div>
 )
}

function addPropData() {
 return prop.data.name
}
```

I know this does not work -- what I am wondering is whether or not there is a way to get it to work?  If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: You can pass `props` as an argument into your function as such, `addPropData(props)`, and accept `props` as a parameter for your function, `function addPropData(props)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the variable into the function.

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>{addPropData(props)}</div>
  )
}

function addPropData(props) {
  return props.data.name
}
```

In context, something like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="like_button_container"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
  const MyComponent = (props) => {
    return (
      <div>{addPropData(props)}</div>
    )
  }
  
  function addPropData(props) {
    return props.data.name
  }
  
  function App() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <MyComponent data={{ name: "myname" }} />
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container')
  const e = React.createElement
  ReactDOM.render(e(App), domContainer);
</script>
```